# Some luck involved

Tags: knowledge, visual, no-computers

Can you guess the theme?

[image]

OK, feel free to reverse image search, it's been many days now.

Slight Tip:

> I expect this kind of `knowledge` to be more common among people born in the 80s.

Tip 1:

> H=0x, Green=1x, 2=2x, Red=Denied

Tip 2:

> One of the images should be considered in French

Last Tip:

> It's about a board game.

Comment: "OK, feel free to reverse image search, it's been many days now." Do you think people would not have done it?

Comment: Beach, Volcano, Poverty/Famine, Crown, Star, US - Russian relationship, Safari, Mumtaz. What is the theme here?

Comment: I see a few loose connections between photos, but nothing that ties more than two or three of them together.  Maybe a another hint is warranted?

Comment: I'm still obsessed with this one. But would really benefit from another hint.

Comment: OK! I am being careful to include tips that won't take much part of the challenge off.

Comment: Are the connections between the images row-oriented?(row1 represents "x", row2 represents "y", row3 represents "z")

Comment: no, nothing like that. X is the cost.

Comment: "One of the images should be considered in French." So the last one is Monalisa's long lost sister?

Comment: @Manojk Kumar heh, nice one. No, tip #2 regards one of the pictures in the middle "row"

Comment: I'm not as obsessed, but I did try connecting dots on a map, finding some interesting inferences. Russian Star and Hawaii appear referenced in two photos. Sirius is also a brand name of boomerang.  And maybe those folks on safari are taking pictures with Fuji film in their cameras.  Unless I've come anywhere close, I think it's time for the answer to be revealed.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis - are you going to reveal the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes then....

This is a reference to Hasbro's board game "Hotels" (actually "Hotel" in some regions). Each picture refers to one of the game's hotel chains.

The first picture is a photo of `Waikiki`, a neighbourhood in Honolulu.

The second picture is a photo of the volcano `Fujiyama`.

In the third picture, the indegenous man is holding a `Boomerang`.

The crown in the fourth picture is a symbol of `Royal`ty.

Fifth picture, a star - `L'etoile` in French.

In the sixth picture you can see two `President`s.

In the seventh picture, people are on a `Safari`.

The last picture is a depiction of Mumtaz Mahal, the tomb of whom is the `Taj Mahal`.

With these, all hints are covered except #2, which refers to the game's build-permission die, which allows you to built for free with H, normal price with green, double price with 2, and forbids you to build with red.